# Set the Arithmetic Precision Globally in C# Apps

Tags: c#, .net, math, .net-core, json.net

We are designing an app which contains multiple microservices in .NET CORE where they communicate via REST API. One important issue I have noticed is the arithmetic precision across all the services and it seems they got out of hand.

In our DTOs, we have *double* and *decimal* types and use NewtonSoft to serialize our objects.

I searched a lot but I am not sure what would be a resolute solution to address the issue. Should we have a middleware to look up all API responses and set the arithmetic precision or is there anything that we can at the serialization stage?

**Update**:
Here is a sample of a DTO:

```
public class HouseDTO
{
   public double Area { get;set;}
   public double Perimeter {get;set;}
   public double Price {get;set;}
   /// other properties
   // ..
   // ..
}
```

We have more than 100 of such DTOs in our services which get calculated.

As an example, here is a JSON generated for one:

```
{
 "area":1029.2542879232,
 "perimeter": 4798.4979
  "price": 429201.429723
}
```

I was wondering how to set precision globally in a service whereby all double values get rounded off by an arbitrary number of decimal places.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the issue? What does "got out of hand" mean?

Comment: https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/1726

Comment: Sounds interesting, but it would help a lot if you give some examples of the problems you are running into.

Comment: @RobertDodier question updated

Comment: @Haytam question updated

Comment: Amir, thanks for the additional information. My advice is, don't try to do this. JSON is just a storage format. When you change the values which are stored, it's no longer possible to retrieve the same thing which was stored. That can lead to subtle bugs down the road.